# Exceptions in unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5, noclassdeffounderror

I copied a unit test that was in a book. exactly the same. There is no problem in compiler but when it runs there are some exceptions. Is there any problem in my codes? if no so what is the reason and what is the solution?

This is my class:

```java
package Testing;

public class MessageUtil {

    private String message;

    public MessageUtil(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String printMessage() {
        System.out.println(message);
        return message;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
}
```

This is test case:

```java
package Testing;

import org.junit.Test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TestJunit extends TestCase {
    String message = "Hello World";
    MessageUtil messageUtil = new MessageUtil(message);

    @Test
    public void testPrintMessage() {
        assertEquals(message,messageUtil.printMessage());
    }
}
```

This is test runner:

```java
package Testing;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
}
```

This is printed exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestCase
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:825)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:723)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at Testing.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.TestCase
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: You dont have Junit jar in your libraries/build path.

Comment: And this looks really strange. The `TestCase` class that is JUnit **3**, that is like a million years outdated. At the same time you are tagging with JUnit **5**. I think the very first thing for you to do: get a better book. You really shouldnt learn JUnit **3** style testing.

Comment: And yes, the exception you get means: your runtime **class path** setup is incorrect. You are not telling the JRE where to look for classes it needs to run your code.

Comment: Did you buy the book in an antiquarian bookstore? Your code smells a lot like Java 1.4 or even older, which would date it at something like 15-30 years old.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using an outdated book to learn JUnit. My initial suggestion would be to buy an updated one, covering the latest version of JUnit, or look for documentation directly on the JUnit website: https://junit.org/junit5/

Answering your question, the *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException* is thrown when the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) tries to load a class and this specified class cannot be found in the classpath. In your case, the type *junit.framework.TestCase* was not found by the JVM, so it wasn't able to compile/run your Java program.

You can resolve this issue by adding JUnit Jar to your classpath. Take a look at this page to find out how to do that: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/how-to-set-classpath-in-java/

Ps: You didn't mention which IDE you are using, so I suggest you start by taking a look into VisualStudioCode with the Java Extension Pack installed, as suggested here: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-vscode.